# React app need to fill an array in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I was filling an array directly from a promise, but then I realized I need to add some html to the array so I was attempting to use a for loop.

```
pullData().then((response) => {
    //previously populated medication array from response like this
    this.setState({medications: response});

    //now I wish to loop  how can I put data in , push data in?
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
       // push data into array?  
       this.medications.push <a onclick={`jsfunction(${response[i].value}) href=javascript:void(0);`}>{`${response[i].value}`}</a>;

    }

});
```

I realize there are map functions,  but I just want to get data into my array.  there are two columns,   "value" and "short_description"

Comment: What is the issue with your code? It looks as if you should update the state after the loop, for visual changes to happen. It is hard to help you out without knowing what you are trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: cab you please describe your prblm statement a little bit what you want to achieve

Comment: Can you please provide the console log of `this.medications` after setState

Comment: [setState is not a synchronous operation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so expecting the value of `this.medications` to be reflected just after `this.setState()` statement is not correct. Moreover, all the rendering logic must be placed inside the `render` function (or other lifecycle methods bases upon on your need), where it is always assured the updated values will be received. So, try using the loop logic inside any of these functions

Comment: Also, [directly updating the state is not a good idea](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) (`this.medications.push...`), as it will not re-render the component and your UI might not actual represent the updated state

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are mentioning seems unclear. As per my understanging, you want to fetch those data and show it as a list.

Here try this one

```
pullData().then((response) => {
let adding_list=[];
//if you want to append the response in previous list uncomment below line
let adding_list=this.state.medications;
//beleiving that the response is an array
response.map((item)=>{
adding_list.push( <a onclick={`jsfunction(${item.value}) href=javascript:void(0);`}>{`${item.value}`}</a>);
}
this.setState({medications:adding_list});
});
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the push,  I have json data and need it to be like this `0: {value: "VICODIN      TAB ", short_description: "VICODIN      TAB 5-300MG"}`

Comment: Instead i'm getting the data this this :  `0: "VICODIN      TAB "`

Answer (score 0):

You cant just update state by calling `this.medications.push()`

You can update state inside for loop like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    let newMedication = <a onclick={`jsfunction(${response[i].value}) href=javascript:void(0);`}>{`${response[i].value}`}</a>;

    this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
            medications: [...prevState.medications, newMedication]
        }
    })
}
```

Or you can save the new medications to a new array and then update state:

```
let allMedications = [];

for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    allMedications.push(<a onclick={`jsfunction(${response[i].value}) href=javascript:void(0);`}>{`${response[i].value}`}</a>);
}

this.setState({
    medications: allMedications
})
```

Comment: Need my data to be like this json  `0: {value: "VICODIN      TAB ", short_description: "VICODIN      TAB 5-300MG"}`     but instead ( i did temporarily get rid of the onclick and replace with `response[i].value`  , but then i get the wrong result set

Comment: I end up with `"VICODIN      TAB "`    -  so I gather i need to have json stringify?  i should construct the value and short_description fields ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller can you add your updated code in question together with what are you expecting and what the currently result is?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
pullData().then((response) => {

   const modifiedResponse = response.map((item) => {
         const modifiedValue = <a onClick={() => this.jsfunction(item.value, item.short_description)} href="javascript:void(0);">{item.value}</a>;

         item.value = modifiedValue;
         return item;
  });


   this.setState({medications:modifiedResponse});

});
```